# No ethernet connection on Intel® X722 10GBase-T Ethernet Controller on Ubuntu-Server 18.04 and 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, intel, supermicro

I'm trying to connect a server with installed Ubuntu-Server to the Internet via Ethernet cable with no success.

Here is the link to the platform we use - https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/4u/7049/sys-7049p-trt.cfm

The cable itself is fine (we tested connection on a laptop). When plugged into one of two LAN ports on the server LED slowly flickers green (approx once in 5 seconds).

We tried both Ubuntu-Server 22.04 and 18.04 with same results.

Running `ip a` command outputs

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:0f:7a:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:0f:7a:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and turning devices eno1 and eno2 off and back on doesn't remedy the situation.

Running `ethtool eno1` shows

```
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                            1000baseKX/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseKR/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
                            1000baseKX/Full 
                            10000baseT/Full 
                            10000baseKR/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Other
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

From what I researched (I looked up this guide https://devicetests.com/troubleshoot-eth0-no-carrier-find-ip-address-ubuntu) seems like `NO-CARRIER` status from `ip a` and `Link detected: no` should mean that cable is disconnected but it's not the case.

Changing speed and duplex through `sudo ethtool -s eno1 speed 100 duplex full` doesn't work and outputs

```
Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting speed
  not setting duplex
```

We also checked network controller drivers but seems like they are installed as could be judged from `modinfo i40e` output

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-156-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/i40e/i40e.ko
version:        2.1.14-k
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection XL710 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <e1000-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>
srcversion:     304E7F43D32C80652A1A2A9
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000158Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000158Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001588sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001587sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037D2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037D1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037D0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037CFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000037CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001589sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001586sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001585sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001584sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001583sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001581sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001580sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001574sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001572sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ptp
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           i40e
vermagic:       4.15.0-156-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all), Debug mask (0x8XXXXXXX) (uint)
```

Running `dhclient -v eno1` shows `No DHCPOFFERS received`

Also during our research we encountered this thread (https://community.intel.com/t5/Server-Products/NIC-X722-for-10GBASE-T-rev-09-Ubuntu-Server-20-04-02-Can-t/td-p/1286202) that might be similar to our situation. Our setup would correspond to Picture 1 from the original post as our network also uses DHCP. Another similarity is that physically moving the server to another room and/or assigning it a static IP might also be problematic in our case.

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The primary difference in your linked thread between what worked and what didn't was the length of wire in the wall. I know you've checked it, but I'd still suspect the cable - get another one, actually might be good to get it significantly longer than required, and try that. One time when I saw something like this, decades ago, it was card and switch both trying auto-crossover at the same time with the same retry interval; a slightly longer cable might prevent that if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my server.

I just added a cheap USB network adapter for Ubuntu installation. After installation and a full system update, using the USB network adapter, my 10GBase worked fine, so I was able to remove my USB network adapter. The reason for this problem seems to be a bug/error within the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Thanks! Although bug persisted even after installation, I decided that leaving USB network adapter was good enough in my situation

Comment: You might want to try Debian (https://www.debian.org/) or openSUSE (https://www.opensuse.org/#Leap) instead of Ubuntu. openSUSE is really comfortable, using the allround system managing tool YAST (just "yast" in CLI).

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the firmware to fix the link issue.  It is a known issue see [here](https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/servers/thinksystem/sr650/7x05/solutions/ht508005-link-issues-with-intel-x722-network-adapter-lenovo-thinksystem) in regards to the x722 with Lenovo servers.

Supermicro has their own update, but you need to email support to recieve the driver from them, they do not make these file available online.

Alternatively you can download direct from Intel [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19223/non-volatile-memory-nvm-update-utility-for-intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x722-series-for-intel-server-board-s2600wf-wft-wfq-wf0-family.html?wapkw=x722).  Read the README in the linux directory for information on how to update the firmware.