# No Wired Connections in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, ethernet

I recently installed Ubuntu desktop 23.04.3 on a ThinkSystem RS630 Lenvovo server.

I have connected the server to my a working ethernet cable but I get no Wired Connection options on the network settings. And of course no internet connection.

(I am new to all of this so please bear with me - I've put as much information as I can based on my searches below)

This is all I see:
[image]

Running: lshw -C network:
[image]

Running: ip a
[image]

I have tried a number of things based on other answers: I tried installing build essentials but was unsuccessful given I have no internet connection

I tried modifying /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf file to:
[image]

I do have an Ethernet controller based on this:
[image]

Needless to say, after 5 hours of searching I have no idea what else to try.

Edit:
I also tried Ubuntu 22.04 and 18.04, but no luck

Comment: Are sure the type is correct because i tried to check the Lenovo site if there where any drivers and i couldn't find that model number. I also did saw that a lot of network adapters where not yet certified for 22.04,so i assume 23* also not. Try to downgrade to 18.04. Maybe first use a live cd

Comment: @Turdie Linux doesn't remove kernel modules often. If it works on older kernels it works on newer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No ethernet connection on Intel® X722 10GBase-T Ethernet Controller on Ubuntu-Server 18.04 and 22.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/1143801/no-ethernet-connection-on-intel-x722-10gbase-t-ethernet-controller-on-ubuntu-se)

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 18.04 as well it's the same thing.

Comment: @Hasam, had been there, until the card works out of the box on your favorite distro, what you want to do is to find a dkms-based driver and test if it is reliable. A candidate off the internet: https://github.com/basvandervlies/i40e-dkms .

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the driver for the X722.  Go to: [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18026/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-pcie-40-gigabit-ethernet-network-connections-under-linux.html?wapkw=x722) and download the
Generic Linux driver.  or you can use this [Direct link to the driver](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/786085/i40e-2.23.17.tar.gz) for verion 2.23.17

You need to decompress the drive by running:

```
 tar -xzvf i40e-*.tar.gz
```

To install the driver run:

```
cd i40e*/src
make install
modprobe i40e
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried this though but nothing seems to work unfortunately

Comment: has lshw -C network changed?  If UNCLAIMED is still showing, we still have some work to do with getting the driver installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- Check on the BIOS if you can upgrade its firmware.
- You can also check the switch combination inside the server (if any)
- You may also want to check the installation configuration since network setup should be setup during initial setup.
- I would suggest you try to install [Ubuntu 22.04LTS](https://ubuntu.com/certified/201708-25651). Once installed, you may verify if network configuration is available in /etc/netplan or show ip addr command. In addition you may install Desktop environment on your ubuntu server following this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-a-gui-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Following command to find and up the connection from terminal.

```
sudo ip link show
```

This will let you know the active and inactive connection to your ubuntu machine.

After, then enable the device connection you want.

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
```